# Migrate iTunes Library *with* meta-data to a new machine

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, itunes

How can I move my iTunes library **including the meta-data** to a new machine of mine.

Both are running `OSX 10.6.5`.

---

### Edit

I unfortunately did not use the default folders for my music directory.

Comment: By copying it? Mount it over the network and copy the iTunes folder via the Finder. Is there something I don't understand about your question?

Comment: NReilingh's answer is the best you can get for that little information you provide. More details might give a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

In order to bring your music to the default folders, do this:

On your existing machine, go to File -> Library -> Organize Library... and choose Consolidate files. This will copy all of your music to `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music` in your Home directory.

The metadata is all stored inside `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml`

The most seamless way I can envision this is just by replacing the `~/Music/iTunes` folder on your new machine with the one from your old one. Then you'll be getting all of your music, which should now be in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music` as well as the metadata in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml`

Answer (score 0):

If you used the default folders for the music and the library, a copy paste should do it, the meta-data is in a xml file on the iTunes main library folder, just make sure both itunes are the same version, and the new iTunes will have the exact same everything as the old one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, simplest way: [echodio](http://www.echodio.com/) + [dropbox](http://dropbox.com). Go with 1 GB per time, or so.